# jQuery compare object always resulting false

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there anything wrong?

i searched google many of them said just simply use == is ok

but while i run the following code

```
<body>
<button id="A" type="button">A</button>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $("#A");
    $("#A").click(function(){
        alert($(this)==temp);
    });
});
</script>
```

The result is always false;

Can any one help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not compare two objects with `==`. *temp* holds the reference of the element. So the reference is compared not the actual element.

Try with `.is()`

```js
console.log({}=={}); // false

$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $("#A");
    $("#A").click(function(){
        alert($(this).is(temp));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="A" type="button">A</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we compare two objects using equal to operator in javascript, it always compares their references not the actual value. Here you are comparing two objects, whose reference are different, thats why you are getting false.